# Batch file with a part of code with XX loop (variable number of loop)

Tags: loops, batch-file

I need to create a batch files with a part of code with a dynamic loop, after completed the loop, continue with the rest of code.

IMPORTANT REQUEST

> The batch file must ask to me to write the loop number to perform with prompt (the number of times to repeat the code).

EXAMPLE OF STEPS TO DO:

> 1 step: I open tha batch file (click on batch files)
>
> 2 step: The batch file ask to me: Number of loop to execute?
>
> 3 step: I put example 10 or another number and confirm my choice
>
> 4 step: Batch files run for 10 loops the part of code
>
> 5 step: After finish the loop part the batch file run the part of code with no loop
>
> 6 step: batch file end

Can you help me with an example where I can specify the part of code to looped and the part with no loop with a prompt request to add the number of loop to do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set /p` to get user input, `for /l` for a loop:

```
set /p "loops=Number of loops: "
for /l %%i in (1,1,%loops%) do (
  echo %%i
)
echo loop end.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, where i can add the loop code (the part of code to loop) and where i can add the part of code to be not loop ? Example: open blocknotes 5 times (part of code for loop), after open taskmanager (part of code for no loop). Thanks

Comment: come on - if it really shouldn't be obvious, run the code and see what's done several times and what's done just one time. You asked thirteen questions, only three of them show code at all. We are here to help you solving your coding problems, not to do your work for you.

Comment: I used your code and works like a charms, thanks. I replaced echo commands with the code to open software and it works, Thanks